# How to preserve browser history in a photo gallery like facebook does?

Tags: facebook, image-gallery, browser-history

I'm developing a photo gallery that uses **ajax**. I'm using **_escaped_fragment_ (#!)** too, it already works but when you use the **back and fwd browser buttons** the url change (the hash fragment) but the image doesn't. I read about the **onHashChange** event but i wanto to know if there's an automatic way to do this, i mean, if there's a way to preserve the DOM changes in the history just like Facebook does.

I change the hash fragment with:

```
window.location.hash = "!"+sth
```

I load ajax content retrieving the hash fragment and using it as index of my photo:

```
var fragment = window.location.hash.replace("#!","");
if (fragment != ""){
  currentItem = fragment;
  currentItemBZ = fragment-1;
  focused = currentItemBZ;
}
```

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this jQuery plugin in the past to retain back-button and history functionality in an ajax-based application:

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

You can register an on change listener, and then change the image in your gallery depending on the new value of the hash.

Comment: it is a great plug in thanks, i'm not using it right now because i wanted something short (not another request) i solved it by creating a simple onhashchange event listener and i'm not gonna fight with IE 6 since the main functionality is preserved